# Unable to get access token with oauth_verifier, keep getting 401 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I saw many questions about the same problem, but I just cannot find a way around so I'm asking a question to be sure I did not miss a thing.

On twitter, I set the callback_url to 'https://my_app_url/'.

```
# consumer
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new('consumer_id', 
                                'secret_key',
                                :site => 'https://api.twitter.com')

# request_token
@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => "https://my_app_url/?state=#{state}")

# then get the user to log in via
login_url = @request_token.authorize_url

# I have a params[:oauth_token] and params[:oauth_verifier] in return
# I don't know what the oauth token is for
# I then should be able to get an access token

# all oauth calls are done in an object so @request_token has been conserved.
@access_token = @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])

# then it happens.
# => 401 Unauthorized
```

I have no idea why the 401 is being raised. Is there a step I have been missing? 
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_request_token` gives you temporary OAuth tokens to authenticate you during the OAuth authentication flow. The OAuth verifier is something that proves that the user authorized the application. You have to give this last to `get_access_token` in order to get the final OAuth tokens that will be used for all your authenticated requests.

For further informations, consider reading the official Twitter documentation dealing with this : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter for the description of the process)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had a miss in my code and the request_token was not properly saved so I was getting access_token from a new generated request_token which was not matching the oauth_verifier I got in return.